# Moving a file from a directory to a network share programmatically

Tags: .net, file-io, network-share

I am attempting to write a process that will move a file from a directory on a server, to a network share, that will not be on that computer.  The methodology worked just fine when moving from my local machine to the network share.  However, it is not working when I put the process on my server (this process is basically a dll, that gets picked up by a running service, the service spins up a thread, gives it to my process, and away it goes).  The process is running using an identity that has access to the shared directory, but it just won't move it.  I can't detect an exception occuring either.  I have pretty good logging in there and no exceptions seem to be thrown.  I will look closer, but has anyone tried to do anything like this before?  I call either this...

```
File.Move(@"C:\Output\" + FileTitle, ShareDirectory + "\\" + FileTitle);
```

Or this...

```
 File.Copy(@"C:\Output\" + FileTitle, ShareDirectory + "\\" + FileTitle, true);
```

depending on whether or not the file exists or not...
I am not certain impersonating anything would solve anything?  The service already runs under an ldap username that has access to the share...

**UPDATE: More information discovered**

Ok, I had an incorrect condition that was never hit,  so that is why I wasn't catching an exception...  I get this exception...

```
Exception Publishing Document to Share: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.
```

Once I saw that exception I decided to impersonate a valid user...
And I am still getting that exception... Would mapping that directory on the server help at all?
I am guessing no, but I am running out of ideas.

**UPDATE: when I impersonate myself vs other users**

When I impersonate my self in the process I am able to successfully move the file to the share.  But If I impersonate another username that should have the same rights, I still get the above exception.  I am not certain why this is occurring.  Maybe this user doesn't have the permissions that I suspect it has.  But just looking in windows and looking at the LDAP server it appears as though it does.  Very curious indeed.

Comment: It _may_ have to do with [.Net Trusts level](https://julianscorner.com/wiki/programming/caspol_network_share), I'm not sure though..

Comment: You are certain that the impersonated user has permissions to both the file system directory **and** the network share? (not the same thing)

Comment: I am double checking.  But I think so.  Unless there is some unseen exemption I am missing I suspect the user has the correct permissions.