# FTP a file in .net

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftp-client

I am looking to move a file from a directory on a server to a file share using a process running out that server already.

I want to know the best way to do this using the ftp protocol.  My initial thoughts on how to do this were to use System.Net.FtpWebRequest... I will probably end up using this, but it looks like there may be some problems with it.  To see what I mean check out the following link...'

[See What I mean](http://mattmitchell.com.au/ftpwebrequest-is-broken/)

That being said, in that article, he listed some other libraries that might be of use.  Has anyone used any of these libraries?  Would it be a good idea for me to try these out?  Or should I just stick with FtpWebRequest.  I will only be uploading a small file, and maybe it is not worth the time learning new libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are moving a file from a local server to a path accessible by network share from that server then there is no need to use FTP, you could just use `File.Copy()`

Comment: I am running into permission issues with File.Copy.  I have a thread about it, if you want to look at it and give me some advice... The long and short of it is the process that is moving the file over is running under a user that should have permission to write to the end direcotry.  However, I get an exception indicating that it does not have said permission.  Not sure why, when I use my username which has the same level of rights, the process will right, not sure what the problem is.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628412/moving-a-file-from-a-directory-to-a-network-share-programmatically

Comment: Well, I would consider setting up an ftp server to do just this simple task would be overkill. Personally, I'd try to get the `File.Copy` working, I have commented on your other thread.

Comment: That advice worked.  Turns out I was using a username that was supposed to have permissions... but didn't.  Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use the [SSH.NET Library](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) found over on Codeplex for its ability to use SFTP.  You did not mention if security,encryption or compression was a requirement but this is a pretty tight little port over from java that runs in .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used the FTPWebRequest on many projects without any problems. As long as you don't need implicit SSH functionality, .NET rocks!!

Here is a tutorial I've written on how to go about creating an FTP client in VB.NET:
http://dot-net-talk.blogspot.in/2008/12/how-to-create-ftp-client-in-vbnet.html

Here is the open-source library of an ftp client I've coded in C#:
http://libftp.codeplex.com/